# Postgres каскадное удаление с триггером

Tags: sql, postgresql, триггер, plpgsql

Есть следующая структура бд

```
table a (
    id     bigint primary key,
    del    timestamp
);
table b (
    id     bigint primary key,
    a_id   bigint references a(id) on delete cascade,
    del    timestamp
);
```

При удалении записи из таблицы `a` я хочу выставить флаг `del` в текущее время и каскадно выставить соответсвующий флаг в таблице `b`.

Чтобы мне это сделать, я пишу триггер

```
create or replace function a_delete_trigger()
    returns trigger as
$$
begin
    update a
    set del = now()
    where id = old.id; -- помечаю время удаления записи

    return null; -- возвращаю null, чтобы запись не удалилась из бд
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
create trigger a_delete
    before delete
    on a
    for each row
execute procedure a_delete_trigger();
```

И вещаю такой же триггер на таблицу `b` :

```
create or replace function b_delete_trigger()
    returns trigger as
$$
begin
    update b
    set del = now()
    where id = old.id;

    return null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
create trigger b_delete
    before delete
    on b
    for each row
execute procedure b_delete_trigger();
```

Когда я удаляю запись из таблицы `а`, она помечается как удаленная ( проставляется время), но запись из таблицы `b` не помечается, как удаленная ( судя по всему, не происходит каскадное удаление).

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при удалении записи из таблицы `a` записи помечались как удаленные и в `а`, и соответствующие записи в таблице `b`?

Answer (score 1):

Фактически в `postgresql` механизм `foreign keys` - это триггеры. Для `delete` получается `after delete for each row` триггер. Несколько триггеров на одно и то же действие допустимы и исполняются в порядке before/instead/after, для равнозначных - в порядке сортировки своих имён.

В случае если триггер возвращает специальное значение `NULL` - это [прерывает выполнение](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html) цепочки триггеров.

> If more than one trigger is defined for the same event on the same
>    relation, the triggers will be fired in alphabetical order by trigger
>    name. In the case of BEFORE and INSTEAD OF triggers, the
>    possibly-modified row returned by each trigger becomes the input to
>    the next trigger. If any BEFORE or INSTEAD OF trigger **returns NULL**,
>    the operation is abandoned for that row and subsequent triggers are
>    **not fired** (for that row).

И в результате получаем, что сначала вызывается ваш `before delete` триггер, он возвращает `NULL` и этим [отменяет выполнение](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/executor/nodeModifyTable.c#L605) вообще всего `delete` для этой строки. Разумеется, `foreign key`, которые в действительности `after delete` триггера - просто не вызываются.

---

Не советую делать как вы задумали. Это к ошибкам. Например, легко можно сломать foreign key и получить несогласованное состояние базы. Триггеры без проблем - это дополнительные действия, а не замещение штатной логики. Замещать логику можно, но легко и отстрелить ногу, как вы уже заметили.

Явная логика здесь была бы:

- отозвать права delete для таблицы
- сделать хранимую процедуру, которая выполняет необходимые действия
- вызывать эту хранимку вместо delete запроса

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Тут в хранимке дело в том, что мне логику для удаления надо будет там расписывать, а я хотел не расписывая ее сделать ( используя cascade delete)